# Opening Images in Android

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I am working on displaying images for some time and have been through the [training](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on the developers website. The one question that still bugs me is how does the default gallery app display high resolution images. Why does it never encounter the java.lang.OutofMemoryError while displaying image? Also, Is there a way I can use the default gallery application in my app to display images?

Comment: it does not display high resolution image, it display proportionally scaled thumbnails in gallery with memory management and better garbage collection.

Comment: when you click on the thumbnails it shows images which looks pretty high res. What do you mean by proportionally scaled thumbnails? The image never pixelates

Comment: I am talking about the gallery itself, not viewing a single Image.

Comment: So how does the gallery work when viewing single Image. Why is there never an outofmemoryerror?

Comment: I just tried opening an 8Mb image in gallery with a resolution of 10k x 10k. There was no error or crash.

Comment: Add your code that makes the error.

Comment: Although this is not a place to such a question but by default it gallery have 73 MB more or less in memory